# git docs - does "upstream" always mean "server-side branch"?

Tags: git

> If the **upstream** branch already contains a change you have made (e.g.,
>   because you mailed a patch which was applied upstream), then that
>   commit will be skipped. For example, running git rebase master on the
>   following history (in which A' and A introduce the same set of
>   changes, but have different committer information): 
>   https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

```
      A---B---C topic
     /
D---E---A'---F master
```

**QUESTION**

I thought "upstream" is always supposed to refer to server-side version of branch.

Why do the docs use it this way? And what does it mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible to use `git branch -u anotherbranch` to set upstream to another local branch. Remotes need not be involved at all, they merely set up upstreams by default in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

> Checking out a local branch from a remote-tracking branch
>   automatically creates what is called a “tracking branch” (and the
>   branch it tracks is called an “upstream branch”). Tracking branches
>   are local branches that have a direct relationship to a remote branch.
>   If you’re on a tracking branch and type git pull, Git automatically
>   knows which server to fetch from and which branch to merge in.
>   - https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

When you have a local branch that tracks a remote branch (e.g., master tracks origin/master) then the branch on origin is considered "upstream". When you rebase, you break that tracking relationship by altering history; therefore, you technically create a new branch of the same name with a different HEAD and a different commit history. That's why you then have to force-push to overwrite the version on the remote origin (e.g., `git push -uf origin my-feature-branch`).

A common rebase I'll do is `git rebase master` from the context of some feature branch. If I rebase from master, then I'm going "upstream" from where I was to replay the commits from master before my feature commits. This is often better than a merge because it keeps the history clean and leaves your feature changes on the top of the `git log --pretty=oneline`.